# python qpid message encoding

Tags: python, encoding, message, amqp, qpid

I'm trying to receive messages from amqp broker in python. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
import getopt
from qpid.messaging import *
from qpid.log import enable, DEBUG

broker_rcv = "admin/admin@hostname:IP"
address_rcv = "broadcast.QUEUE_NAME.QUEUE_NAME"  + "; { node: { type: queue }, assert: never , create: never, mode: " + "browse" + " }"

connection_rcv = Connection(broker_rcv)
connection_rcv.open()
session_rcv = connection_rcv.session()
receiver = session_rcv.receiver(address_rcv)

msg = receiver.fetch(timeout=None)
print msg.content
```

But when I try to print messages I see them in strange encoding and there is no way how to change message encoding.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Post some of the strangely encoded strings.

Comment: AEDEXCHAED"AEDN0 :UAE DIRHAMS   @H R


EURAED     XLâ  H
ANGEXCHANG"ANGN0 :NETHERLANDS   @H R


EURANG     XLâ  H
AUDEXCHAUD"AUDN0 :AUSTRAL DOLLAR@H R


EURAUD     XLâ  H
AZNEXCHAZN"AZNN0 :AZERBAIJAN    @H R

Comment: If I delete print and left just msg.content I recive message like this: \n2\xa2\x06/\n\x0520001\x12\nEUREX 14.0\x1a\x05EUREX \x01*\x07\x08\xcd\x0f\x10\x0b\x18\x0c0\x00:\x06\x08\x0e\x10\x13\x18\x0e\x12L\x8a\xe2\tH\n\x03AED\x12\x04EXCH\x1a\x03AED"\

Answer (score 0):

msg.content contains the original message content sent by some producer. You cannot change it.
And what is the encoding you metioned above? If you saw that when print msg, just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is that you are failing to decode the messages. When you receive an encoded message, you have to begin by decoding it.

Are those FIX messages?  All the technical specs are here http://fixprotocol.org/specifications/

One Python library is here http://source.kentyde.com/fixlib

Comment: My message is in google protobuf. I have manged to decode it using decoder.